# ¿Cómo veo qué filas hay en una base de datos SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Lo que quiero hacer es sacar el índice de las filas de una base de datos, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la consola de sqlite, podes hacer un `.schema {table_name}`

Desde python podes hacer asi:

```
import sqlite3
db=sqlite3.connect("...")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info('albums')").fetchall()
[
   (0, 'AlbumId', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 1),
   (1, 'Title', 'NVARCHAR(160)', 1, None, 0),
   (2, 'ArtistId', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)
]
```

Comment: una pregunta que son los ultimos 3 datos que regresa? (1, None, 1)

Comment: cid, name, type, notnull, dflt_value, pk